# path to ffmpeg in linux hosting server

Tags: ffmpeg

what will be the path to ffmpeg on linux server.......

Answer (score 9):

Try `whereis ffmpeg` on the command line.

Comment: +1 because whereis is cool ( http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_whereis.htm ). Thought ffmpeg needs to be listed as a command  in order for it to work isn't it?

Comment: Yes, but `which ffmpeg` is faster to just find the path of a binary :-)

Answer (score 5):

If ffmpeg is in the path, use `which ffmpeg` to find its path.

If it's not in the path, use `locate ffmpeg`.

The fact that it's a server should not change the path where it is installed if you installed it with packages, so it should probably be in `/usr/bin/ffmpeg`.

Answer (score 3):

It might be in the bin, etc... It kinda depends where it got installed.

Use the [find function](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?find) to get it for sure.

Answer (score 1):

On a hosted Linux server, it may not even be installed. Probably depends on your hosting package.

But if it is installed, /usr/bin (for the executable) and /usr/lib (for the libraries) would be the first place I'd look.

Also, `locate ffmpeg` may be a helpful command to try.

Answer (score 1):

try 'locate', 'which', or 'whereis' ... If all fails, then 'find / | grep ffmpeg'